# ListView and DataPager implementation in FW 3.5 works but misbehaves when project migrated to FW 4.0

Tags: asp.net, listview, .net-4.0, datapager

I have 2 listviews in an asp.net page. Both use a datapager with a dropdown (showing X of X pages, each listview can show just 5 records in a single list page).
Based on selection in the first, I show some items in the second listview and I also have ability to add new items in the second one.

When I add new items in the second listview (using an InsertItemTemplate) I also ensure that if the newly added record is going on the second page, I set the listview to show the second page with the newly added record as the selected item.

All of this works fine using .NET Framework 3.5.
Recently, we migrated our application to Framework 4.0 and since then the Selections & Paging in second listview misbehave (they don't show up). Also the next page logic fails and shows me the EmptyDataTemplate.

Most of my paging related code is based on the DataPager.SetPageProperties() method.

Has anybody noticed any such behavior in Framework 4?